# transpose to columns the top n frequent values by id

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm working on Hive. I wanna feature engineer this table selecting the top 2 most frequent values in the `user_agent` column and put it all in one line, summarizing the information.

I have a database that looks like this:

```
userID | user_agent 
1      |  Windows NT 6.1
1      |  Windows NT 6.1
1      |  Windows NT 6.1
1      |  Macintosh
1      |  Macintosh
2      |  Windows NT 6.1
2      |  Windows NT 6.1
2      |  Macintosh
2      |  X11
3      |  X11
3      |  X11
4      |  Windows NT 6.1
4      |  X11
5      |  iPhone
6      |  X11
6      |  iPhone
7      |  
7      |  
7      |  
7      |  Windows NT 6.1
```

It's import to note that the `user_agent` is way more complex than the used in the example table, having a huge number of unique values, thus I can't work with dummies. (I've tried it)

Let's call the most common value column as `top_1_user_agent` and the second most common column as `top_2_user_agent`.

When there's only a value, the `top_2_user_agent` value must be null, like with the userID 3.
When there's a "draw", like with `userID 2` and `userID 6`, the chosen value must be the first by order in the table.

The result must look like this:

```
userID | top_1_user_agent |   top_2_user_agent 
1      |  Windows NT 6.1  | Macintosh
2      |  Windows NT 6.1  | Macintosh
3      |  X11             | 
4      |  Windows NT 6.1  | X11
5      |  iPhone          | 
6      |  X11             | iPhone    
7      |                  | Windows NT 6.1
```

Any help is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rank()` and `collect_set()` should do it.

```
select userID,collect_set(user_agent)
from 
(
    select *, rank() over (partition by userID,user_agent order by cnt desc) as rank
    from
    (
        select userID,user_agent, count(*) as cnt
        from yourtable
        group by userID,useragent
    ) x
) y
where rank <= 2
group by userID
```

Comment: Oh, you forgot the `group by userID` at the end of the query.

Well, collect_set did most of what i've asked. That's already a great start to me. Thanks!